# работа с yoctoproject, как переделать загружаемый образ

Tags: linux

Вопрос заключается в исправление какого-то сценария сборки на yoctoproject для genericx86. Дело в том что система собирает образ с rootfs.img файлом, но для удобства разработки требуется сделать так, чтобы корневая файловая система располагалась не в отдельном образе, а в корне накопителя как это сделано для beaglebone образов..